# Single .js and .d files for commonjs

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a single .js and .d file for my entire library.
this is my package.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "build",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "watch": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "outFile": "file.js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "build"
    ]
}
```

but when I run `tsc` I get this error: `error TS6082: Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --outFile.`

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a conceptual thing. Commonjs modules are resolved in a way that concatenating them into one file doesn't make sense. See this thread in the TypeScript issues for details:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7252

If you build your library as commonjs, you could of course provide some index file that imports all your other files and exports the parts under separate keys so that you can import the whole lib or only parts of it.

Comment: Ok, it make sense for .ts, but for .d? It makes?

Comment: That's for the same reason. By aligning the definition files (*.d.ts) directly with all the modules, the TypeScript compiler can import just exactly the parts of the definitions that are used by the consumer of your module. See this post for more details on the reasons of splitting stuff: https://medium.com/@mweststrate/how-to-create-strongly-typed-npm-modules-1e1bda23a7f4#.2xayimlpn

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand this. What do you want to achieve? What's the reason you are using commonjs? Are you targeting node or browser?

Comment: I really can't understand how to deal with commonjs.. I am trying to use core in tagger but it can't find module. Its has been a pain =/

Comment: I am using node, my core library exposes 10 classes, and tagger module and parser module consumes it.

Comment: How do you reference/install your package then? Could you provide a simple git repository describing your setup?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106409/discussion-between-murilokunze-and-ajaegle).